# Accessing a file on the server from my asp.net web application

Tags: iis, permissions

In my asp.net web application I am trying to retrieve images from a shared network folder. When I put this website live in IIS, I am getting an error that "Access to the path is denied" when I try to access the network folder. What is considered the user that IIS uses, and how would I grant permissions to the network folder?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because your application pool identity or the user that IIS is using to run the worker process does not have permissions on the network path.

You may want to grant this user permission on the network path. However, if you are using IIS AppPoolIdentity that is not possible as they are built-in account per machine. As is the same with any buit-in account.

I would advice you to use a network account and give that account appropriate permissions on both IIS and the network share.

You may have to add this user to the IUSR group.